# data type of template reference variable in Angular2

Tags: angular

Where can I find information about the data type of reference variable?

```
<input #my-int .../>
<form #my-form />
```

In above example, `my-int` refers to `input` and `my-form` refers to `ngForm`. I want to know what properties and methods are available to me in `my-int`, `my-form` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the template variables `my-int` has the data type 
[HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) and `my-form` has the type [HTMLFormElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement). The data type depends on the DOM node you are referencing.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do to access those elements and see available props and methods

```
@ViewChild('my-int') input;
ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.input.nativeElement);
}
```

import `ViewChild` with

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. Will try it. Is this information not available in the documentation?

Comment: In the official `ViewChild` documentation I have seen only examles where it is used to see another components' content. But you can use it also to inspect a generic element in the template as I've shown. If the suggested method works please come back to mark the question as answered, thanks

Comment: I got this output `<input name="name" type="text" ng-reflect-name="name" ng-reflect-model="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">` Its not what I am looking for. While reading various tutorials, I found that the several methods and properties are available via template reference variable like 'hasAttribute`, `type`, `value` etc. I want to know where in documentation I can find information about available properties and methods in general.

Comment: try this then `console.log(this.input)` and let me know

Comment: It was helpful but I still couldnt find where 'hasAttrubute' is defined. For eg, I can do `myint.hasAttribute('required')` but I do not know where `hasAttribute` is documented.